# Using PHP to run ANT Build.xml file on Server

Tags: php, ant, build, cron

I'm trying to run a Ant build.xml file via a cronjob. I have seen that i can run system commands with php and wondered whether these could be used to run the ant build file? If so i can then setup a cron job to run the php file every night?

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

For instance i have the following in my php file:

system("ant ./build/cronjob/build.xml");

Although this produces output it doesn't appear to be working?

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: why not directly call ant from cron?  (ant on unix is shell script that launches actual program)

Comment: Hi Jayan, if possible can you give me further information. I am not to sure how to call ant from cron. Any additional information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post your current crontab entry

Answer (score 0):

First step is to ensure you can run `ant ./build/cronjob/build.xml` from command prompt. Creating  cron entry will be then straight forward.

I prefer creating a wrapper script, say  $HOME/scripts/callant.sh.  The script could be like

```
#!bash
#setup variables
BUILD_FILE=/build/cronjob/build.xml
ANT_CMD=/pathtoant/bin/ant
JAVA_HOME=<path to jdk>
#setup path
#setp LD_LIBRARY_PATH ..

$ANT_CMD -f  $BUILD_FILE  > /tmp/$$out.log 2>/tmp/$$err.log
```